# Get json objects value with python

Tags: python, json

I have a problem with my python code. I have successfully merged multiple json files with python. The json code of each file is in a python dict. When I want to use that data it only shows me the object name not the value.

This is the code that adds the code of all json files inside a python dict:

```
result = []
for f in glob.glob("jsons/*.json"):
    with open(f, "rb") as infile:
        result.append(json.load(infile))
```

After that I would like to show all IDs of all the reports from all json files:

```
for files in result:
        for reports in files["reports"]:
                print reports["id"]
```

But I get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 71, in <module>
    print reports["id"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When I delete ["id"] then it shows me a list of all report names (1,2,3,...) but not the full report with objects and values. Only the report names.

Here is the json code:

```
{
    "reports": {
        "1": {
            "id": "123"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "122"
        },
        "3": {
            "id": "121"
        }
    }
},
{
    "reports": {
        "4": {
            "id": "120"
        },
        "5": {
            "id": "119"
        },
        "6": {
            "id": "118"
        }
    }
},
...
```

Comment: Did you try opening those files in text mode instead (replace ```'rb'```, by ```'r'```, in the ```open()``` call)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for reports in files["reports"]:
```

`files["reports"]` is a dictionary, and iterating over a dictionary will only bind the keys of that dictionary, and not its values. So `reports` will be `"1"` and then `"2"` etc.

If you want `reports` to be bound to the `{"id": "123"}` dictionary value instead of the string key, specify this with the `values` method:

```
for reports in files["reports"].values():
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are `lists`, not arrays.

Anyway, we have a `list` of nested `dicts`, and we want to get all the values corresponding to the `id` keys in the innermost `dicts`.

You can do that with a `list` comprehension, as follows:

```
[v['id'] for file in files for v in file['reports'].values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

In correlation to the previous answers, your json converted to a dictionary, so does other formats of json do as below. Adding the "values" method or changing the iteration to (python3)

```
for files in result:
  for k,v in results.items():
   print(k, v)
```

### **JSON         -----        PYTHON**

Object             -----          dict
Array           -----            list
string          -----          unicode 
number(int)   -----        int, long